# Is there an alternative to Google Maps to find GPS coordinates of a place in Germany?

Tags: geospatial

For probably any place on Earth, you can search it in Google Maps, make right-click, pick the option "What's here" and you get GPS coordinates.

[image: english-school]

If I don't want to use Google Maps API, is there an alternative open API to get GPS coordinates by address? To be less broad, say in Germany?

Comment: Never tried, but city mapper API let you probably do it: https://citymapper.3scale.net/

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of APIs for OpenStreetmap, e.g. via [html request](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=pleikartsf%C3%B6rsterstrasse,%20heidelberg&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1):

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=pleikartsförsterstrasse,%20heidelberg&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1
```

A json is returned. You can easily access the type of information you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the api for this particular purpose, but openstreetmap.org has very similar map data access.